# Powershell - DACL, ACE

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dacl

Is there any way to display the ACE mask of an AD object in decimal/hexadecimal, so that instead of "Generic Read" it reads 0x80000000 or 2147483648?

[DACL/ACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vFt5.png)

Comment: You can cast to `[int]`. See [ActiveDirectoryRights Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryrights?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: Or if you prefer not to see negative values, cast to `[Uint32]`